# XCode & Phonegap with $.get function

Tags: xcode, get, cordova, jqtouch

I have a problem, I created a Webapps into HTML and JavaScript to create a native iPhone with PhoneGap. This works properly on Safari browser and iPhone, when compiling with xcode, I have a problem with the $.get function that does not receive data from my external server.
example code:

```
$.get('http://www.mydomain.com/retriveinfo.php', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='data';
    jQT.goTo($('#page-result),'slideleft');
});
```

you can not use $. get? there an alternative? IOS Simulator bug? Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the $. getJSON that allows cross-domain calls